# JSF param POST parameter not retrieving

Tags: javascript, jsf, post

I've been looking an answer, but I don't find anything.

I got a JSF page with a button. This button call a JavaScript function  :

```
function postAdd(id) {
    var quant = document.getElementById("hell:quantite");
   $('<form action="addto.xhtml" method="POST">' + 
    '<input type="hidden" name="productkey" value="' + id + '">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="howmany" value="' + quant.value + '">' +
    '</form>').submit();
}
```

This works fine, I've tested it. 
But in my addto.xhtml page, when I call **param.productkey** and **param.howmany**, I got nothing.

I used this method on other page and works fine but here, it doesn't work...

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to add to form inside the JSF page directly and get all parameters with `#{function(param[form:idOfInput]}`